# Error al guardar en Oracle 11G desde app en C#

Tags: c#, oracle, oracle-11g

quisiera pedir ayuda si alguien sabe que puedo estar realizando mal en este código.
El contexto es que estoy tratando de registar un usuario en mi BDD de mi proyecto de universidad, y me sale el siguiente error, no se si se debe a que el esta dentro de un package el procedimiento u otra cosa.

A continuación les dejo mi código y de antemano muchas gracias:

```
+       $exception  {"ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:\nPLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'SP_AGREGAR_USUARIO'\nORA-06550: line 1, column 7:\nPL/SQL: Statement ignored\n"}  System.Data.OracleClient.OracleException
```

Lo que tengo en mi clase UsuarioDAO es lo siguiente.

```
public bool agregarUsuario(UsuarioCL usuario)
    {
        bool respuesta = false;
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            OracleCommand OC = new OracleCommand("PKG_USUARIO.SP_AGREGAR_USUARIO", conn);
            OC.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            OC.Parameters.Add("CORREO", OracleType.VarChar).Value = usuario.Correo;
            OC.Parameters.Add("PASSWORD", OracleType.VarChar).Value = usuario.Password;
            OC.Parameters.Add("NOMBRE", OracleType.VarChar).Value = usuario.Nombre;
            OC.Parameters.Add("APELLIDOPAT", OracleType.VarChar).Value = usuario.ApellidoPaterno;
            OC.Parameters.Add("APELLIDOMAT", OracleType.VarChar).Value = usuario.ApellidoMaterno;
            OC.Parameters.Add("TELEFONO", OracleType.Number).Value = usuario.Telefono;
            OC.Parameters.Add("ID_TIPO_USUARIO", OracleType.Number).Value = usuario.IdTipoUsuario;
            if (OC.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)
            {
                respuesta = true;
            }                
        }
        catch (Exception exep)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(exep.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
        return respuesta;
    }
```

En la vista WPF

```
private void btnGuardar_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            UsuarioDAO UsuarioDAO = new UsuarioDAO();
            UsuarioCL usuario = new UsuarioCL
            {
                Correo = txtCorreo.Text,
                Password = txtContrasenia.Password.ToString(),
                Nombre = txtNombre.Text,
                ApellidoPaterno = txtApellidoPaterno.Text,
                ApellidoMaterno = txtApellidoMaterno.Text,
                Telefono = decimal.Parse(txtTelefono.Text),
                IdTipoUsuario = 1 
            };
            bool resp = UsuarioDAO.agregarUsuario(usuario);
            MessageBox.Show(resp ? "Usuario guardado" : "Error al guardar usuario");

        }
        catch (ArgumentException exa)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + exa);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Saludos. Mientras llega alguien del tema; te sugiero lo siguiente; revisar el SP que reciba la misma cantidad de parámetros que estas pasando y en ese mismo que c/u de los valores corresponde; por ejemplo observo que **IdTipoUsuario** cuando la asignas es Entero y lo pasas como **OracleType.Number** (decimal); otra posibilidad es la longitud recibida en los datos que son texto.

Answer (score 0):

El error "PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'SP_AGREGAR_USUARIO'" ofrece 2 posibilidades:

1-Que falte algún parámetro para el llamado del procedimiento SP_AGREGAR_USUARIO:
¿está seguro que son 7 parámetros de entrada?
¿alguno de los parámetros está definido con la cláusula "default"?

2-Que alguno de los parámetros sea de tipo numérico y el valor al momento de la llamada al procedimiento contenga algún caracter que impide la conversión automática a un valor de tipo numérico.

Si tiene acceso a la base de datos Oracle con un cliente como "SQL Developer" o "SQLPlus" puede usar el comando "describe PKG_USUARIO" para obtener una descripción de los procedimientos y funciones que contiene y con el detallado de cada uno de los parámetros:

- nombre
- dirección (IN, OUT, IN OUT)
- tipo de dato
- si tiene valor por "default".